# Serving app with Client-Side Routing in NestJs

Tags: api, nestjs

I have a sample react app using react-router-dom with  one route "/reset/:token"

when I run my app in development server and navigate to my route  everything works fine

but in server static using **ServeStaticModule** when I navigate to my route I get "Cannot GET /reset/5T4665" and 404
status code

Here is my code:

**App.module**

```
    @Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: 'config/' + `.${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env`,
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
    MongooseModule.forRoot(`${process.env.MONGO_URI}`),
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'public'),
      renderPath: '/',
    }),
    BullModule.forRoot({
      redis: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 6379,
      },
    }),
  
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Any helps would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by adding Asterisk in field renderPath

```
 ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'public'),
      renderPath: '/*',
    }),
```

Source : https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing